# Com port read on c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, byte, port

Please tell me how to read data from com port in c #, if the data is received in bytes, but of variable length, that is, the answer may be a byte array  20 and 50, that is the main question is, how do you know that the device stopped responding?

Answer (score 1):

The most important part is defining the protocol bits used. You should have both start and stop bits that will tell your SerialPort object when to stop reading. Usually you don't have to care after this since your callback function will contain the data in an array.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to assemble an answer to an array, so that you handle it, but since I do not know when the end response from the device, but the program is constantly trying to read a port, so my question is how one can understand that all port said ended data transmission, you can begin processing the array

Comment: That's up to the protocol of the device. Possibly it will send an 'end transmission' signal, or have a timeout period.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  COM ports are a bit like TCP - they're a streaming service - they only transfer 7 or 8 bits at a time, (depending on how you set the port up, normally 8 bits).

If you want to send anything more complex than a byte, you need to build a protocol on top.  If your data is text, a CR or null at the end will often do.  If it's values in the whole set of bytes 0-255, then you need a more complex protocol to ensure that the framing of the data-units is received correctly.  Maybee your requirements can be met by a simple timeout, eg 'if no chars received for 500ms, that's the end of the data unit', but such timeout-protocols are obviously low performance and subject to failures:(

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Oh - there's the old way.  You can send a 'break' - an illegal framing which can be recognised by the receiving hardware and signaled to the receiving app.  I forgot about it  because no-one uses it anymore.  Apart from anything else, it only works on RS232 links and so the stream cannot then be piped on to anywhere else, eg. over a TCP connection.